# How can I publish MS Access project (forms and all) to the web?

Tags: microsoft-access, web-application

I'm not sure if this is even possible with Access 2007 (or 2010 Beta), but I would like information on ways to make a project with forms, macros and modules accessible via the Web.

Any good links or books would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A starting point on what to expect in A2010 is the [Access development team's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/access/default.aspx).

Also, go to Google Groups and enter this search:

```
  albert kallal 2010 sharepoint group:*access*
```

Albert is a poster here on SO, but he's been a beta tester for A2010 and has a very good idea of what's possible web-wise. It's a pretty amazing set of features, quite a technical accomplishment by Microsoft, seems to me.

The point is that in conjunction with Sharepoint 2010, an Access app using web forms and web reports (a new object type in A2010) will run identically in the web browser via Sharepoint 2010's Access services and in client Access running on the desktop. These new features allow you to use Access to create an app that is accessible via the web browser, something that was previously impossible in any meaningful sense.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to create, modify, or import data access pages is no longer supported in Microsoft Office Access 2007. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA100308321033.aspx